# Getting same hashed value while using BCryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: spring-security, bcrypt

I am using spring security using BCryptPasswordEncoder. Now for change password what I need to do is to compare Existing Password provided by user with DB value.

But since salt is generated dynamically by `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, every time I get different hashed value from below method and not necessarily it would match with my DB value.

```
public static String encodePassword(String password) {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
    return hashedPassword;
}
```

What's the remedy for this problem? can I identify salt used for my DB field and use the same salt in above method ?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use the `matches` method on the `PasswordEncoder` interface to check whether the password is valid, rather than encoding it again and comparing with the existing hash.

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String existingPassword = ... // Password entered by user
String dbPassword       = ... // Load hashed DB password

if (passwordEncoder.matches(existingPassword, dbPassword)) {
    // Encode new password and store it
} else {
    // Report error 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using BCryptPasswordEncoder with your own properties (strength / random) together with Spring MVC, then you could declare your PasswordEncoder as a Bean. That way, it will be a singleton instance and you can reuse it.

Here comes an example (I don't know which configuration style you are using):

in your security configuration:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

    int strength = // your strength;
    SecureRandom random = // your random

    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(strength, random);
    return encoder;
}
```

However, in your controller, you can compare passwords like this:

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public boolean checkPassword(String password, String 
    return passwordEncoder.matches(password, hashedPassword);;
}
```

Comment: This isn't right. The whole point of salting the is that a different random salt is used each time you encode a password. It doesn't matter how many instances of the Java class there are.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I misunderstood this. However, using a singleton PasswordEncoder is a good practice if you specify custom properties.