# Compares password from DB (encoded password) and user entered

Tags: java, encoding, passwords, bcrypt

How to compare password entered by user and saved in DB using BCryptPasswordEncoder.

Below is the code we are using to save password in DB:

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String password = encoder.encode("Test"));
DB.save(password);
```

How to check user entered password and above saved password to allow login?

Any suggestions or links which explains above procedure will be of great help?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26818730/905488) might help.

Comment: In short: you probably shouldn't and use Apache Shiro or Spring Security. A bit longer: you take the password the user entered, use the same way of hashing it you used to "encode " the password before saving it in the database and compare if the Strings are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your encoding method will give the same value each time you encode a given string, then:

1. Look up the user by username.
2. Encode the password they typed in, store in memory.
3. Check the encoded value with the value in the Database.  If it matches, then they typed the right password.  If it doesn't match, then they didn't.

Comment: Encoding for a single key/password will give different output strings everytime...

Comment: Can you store 2 password values in your database--one would be the encrypted value, one would be a 1-way hash.  The encrypted value would allow you to decrypt, as needed, and the hash value would give you consistency to compare against, but you could never get the original value back.  Then you could do the method above, but against the hash version.

Comment: Then you are doing sth ***seriously*** wrong. Bcrypt is a Hash function specifically designed for the task described by PhatWrat.

Comment: It looks like Mick Mnemonic found a duplicate with a good answer to this question.  (I'm afraid I don't know anything about BCryptPasswordEncoder specifically)

Comment: @PhatWrat I was referring to OP ;)

Comment: @SpringUser - You get a different output every time, because of the random salt. The `passwordEncoder.matches()` function will extract the salt from the stored hash, so it can use the same salt with the entered password.