# Vaadin4Spring's ManagedSecurity: How to update user list?

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin4spring

I'm using Vaadin 7.5.6, [Vaadins Spring 1.0.0](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/vaadin-spring), the [Vaadin4Spring Managed Security Extension 0.0.7-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/tree/master/extensions/security) and Tomcat8.

Currently, I got a configuration class which implements the [AuthenticationManagerConfigurer](https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/blob/master/extensions/security/src/main/java/org/vaadin/spring/security/config/AuthenticationManagerConfigurer.java) interface:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.vaadin.spring.security.annotation.EnableVaadinManagedSecurity;
import org.vaadin.spring.security.config.AuthenticationManagerConfigurer;

import com.vaadin.server.CustomizedSystemMessages;
import com.vaadin.server.SystemMessages;
import com.vaadin.server.SystemMessagesInfo;
import com.vaadin.server.SystemMessagesProvider;

import de.blume2000.kiss.hibernate.dto.User;
import de.blume2000.kiss.hibernate.services.UserService;
import de.blume2000.kiss.utils.EncryptionUtil;

@Configuration
@EnableVaadinManagedSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration implements AuthenticationManagerConfigurer
{

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        List<User> users = userService.findAll();

        if (users == null)
            return;

        for (User user : users)
        {
            String encryptedPassword = EncryptionUtil.decryptPassword(user.getPassword(), user.getSalt());
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(user.getUsername()).password(encryptedPassword).roles(user.getRole());
        }

    }

    /**
     * Provide custom system messages to make sure the application is reloaded when the session expires.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @Bean
    SystemMessagesProvider systemMessagesProvider()
    {
        return new SystemMessagesProvider()
        {
            @Override
            public SystemMessages getSystemMessages(SystemMessagesInfo systemMessagesInfo)
            {
                CustomizedSystemMessages systemMessages = new CustomizedSystemMessages();
                systemMessages.setSessionExpiredNotificationEnabled(false);
                return systemMessages;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Now if the user did a login he has the option to edit his user account settings. This changes the user object in the database (e.g. the username for login). Now if he does a logout, i want the application to reload the userlist, so the user can use his new username. How is this possible?

Regards
shinchillahh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, replace your in-memory authentication with DAO authentication.

Please note that in the example below [UserDetailsService userService](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) is the Spring core interface, and `UserRepository userRepository` is the DAO for your users (aka `UserService userService` in your example).

**1. Configuration**

```java
@Configuration
public class Authorization extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userService;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**2. Service providing user details**

```java
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this method compatible with the Vaadin4Spring Security extension? So I can handle login and logout via vaadinSecurity.login(...) and vaadinSecurity.logout()?

Comment: @shinchillahh I haven't really tried the add-on, but you're simply switching the `InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer` with a `DaoAuthenticationConfigurer` which should be transparent

Comment: Okay I got it. Do I have to notice something special about the User DTO class? Because the loadUserByUsername(String username) method returns the UserDetails interface...

Comment: @shinchillahh For simplicity I made my `User` bean implement the `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` interface. A nicer and cleaner code would probably create a `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` (or a custom implementation) from your own `User`model bean.

Comment: Im so thankful for your help. I think I know how to do it. Last question: Because I have my own password encryption util I have to define my own password encoder, right? How should I do that?

Comment: @shinchillahh You can either implement yourself the [PasswordEncoder interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444258/how-to-use-new-passwordencoder-from-spring-security) or use one of the encoders already provided such as `BCryptPasswordEncoder`. The main idea is to always [generate the same hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811885/getting-same-hashed-value-while-using-bcryptpasswordencoder) for the same password, otherwise you'll never be able to login.