# JPA - Java Spring Boot - problems finding account with password encoding?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I am new to JPA - I've started to build a user system and added the encoding bean to my pom.

When I do a search on the table for just an email address - it finds the user and comes back with the data.

```
TblLogin acc = tblLoginRepository.findByEmail(email);
```

and the repo I have for this is as follows.

```
public interface TblLoginRepository extends JpaRepository<TblLogin, String> {
    TblLogin findByEmail(String email) throws Exception;
}
```

--
when I try and do a look up with the password encoded it doesn't find the user - and I am not sure why as the data appears correct?

with password

```
TblLogin checkAccount = tblLoginRepository.findByEmailAndPassword(email,passwordEncoder.encode(password));
```

repo2

```
public interface TblLoginRepository extends JpaRepository<TblLogin, String> {
    TblLogin findByEmail(String email) throws Exception;
    TblLogin findByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) throws Exception;
}
```

--

is it because my type for password has changed? - should it be checking for something else...

Comment: what exactly u want? what is the questions?

Comment: -- ok - I'm doing a fetch data on the user account -- I can see that when I try and login -- the password encoding is actually changing - so its not going to find the result... is there a kind of way of getting the same encoding result to do a match with what was stored on the db -- similar to md5(x)

Comment: how encoding is changing? do you declare PasswordEncoding as bean? do you use it during "save" process?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811885/getting-same-hashed-value-while-using-bcryptpasswordencoder

Comment: -- ok so I register the user - with the PasswordEncoding.encode(password)

Comment: but when I did the encode again in the login function - just noticed its regenerating a new hash? -- a reference to this link above I just gave says use the matches method.. PasswordEncoding.matches(just-entered-password, stored-hash-password)? -- but that means doing a lookup on just email first, then pulling out the stored-hash-password and doing the final check?

Comment: "declare PasswordEncoding as bean?" yes --  //beans
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

Comment: -- this works but feels a bit clunky -- I have do find the user via email first - get the stored password -- then do the lookup  --     if(passwordEncoder.matches(password, checkAccount.getPassword())) {
        // Encode new password and store it
     System.out.println("PASSWORD MATCH");
     
    } else {
        // Report error 
     System.out.println("PASSWORD ERROR");
    }

Comment: what they mean is: 1) pull all record (incl. hash) 2) match against hash 3) return record or throw exception .. i prefer moving that piece of functionality as well onto DB and performing a lookup based on id and password hash. can you add SecureRandom (as 2nd parameter) to BCryptPasswordEncoder? As well. remember to always decode/encode against same charset (UTF-8).

Comment: @MironBalcerzak -- you have examples of what you just said - if you could put it in an answer -- especially that encode/decode against charset stuff -- -yeah I saw that securerandom thing - should I put it in?

Comment: If you generate a hash for the same password with the same password encoder, it will return the same hash. Right now we can only speculate why this isn't happening. Maybe your registration doesn't store the hash correctly, maybe you didn't enter the same password, maybe you're using a different passwordencoder or different options, ... .

Comment: If that works depends on your password encoding. Using BCrypt for instance it won't work as the hash changes through time. It would work for things like MD5 (which you shouldn't be using).

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know how you did implement it. Make sure about few things while implementing that functionality.

1 - register PasswordEncoder bean:

```
public PassordEncoder encoder() {
     return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11, new SecureRandom("seed".getBytes("UTF-8)));
}
```

depend on custom "seed" (for security reasons)

2 - make sure you are encoding within same character charset.
As said earlier... I do not know HOW you retrieve your password that you are hashing. Give a try construction (ugly) as follows:

```
 String passwordToHash = new String(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

3 - How do you store hash in your DB? Can you verify whether hash that you generate during "save" process and the one you are having stored after that process is the same?

Hope it helps.

Comment: 1. wants me to add a try/catch method -- or a throw declaration

Comment: 2. I did the matches idea -- where it takes the human readable password - and the stored password (which I get first by doing a lookup just on the email) -- so I get the possible user with the email first -- then do a check on the password entered and password stored  -- if(passwordEncoder.matches(password, checkAccount.getPassword())) {

Comment: 3.-- in the register mapping - I stash the new account like this -- so do a check to see if the email exists -- then do a saveAndFlush --     // if not create some
    TblLogin newAcc = tblLoginRepository.saveAndFlush(new TblLogin(
       email,
       passwordEncoder.encode(password),
       pin
      ));